# взаимодействие файла реализации и conf

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Хочу создать полноценное консольное приложение для ОС без использования интерпретатора python, а скомпилированного файла реализации(~exe файл) с использованием файла конфигурации.

Они находятся в одной директории

```
/usr/bin/date-worker/.
```

я помечаю расположение файла реализации в переменные среды

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/date-worker"
```

Перехожу в другой репозиторий, запускаю

```
pepe@pepe-Aspire-A315-41:~$ dw -h
```

выдает ошибку: не видит date.conf

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'date.conf'
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в том, что я запускал программу из другого репозитория, где функция "open()" пыталась найти мой файл.

```
open('date.conf', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Решение - указать путь к моему конфигурационному файлу

```
open('/usr/bin/date-worker/date.conf', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```